# Get network interface in Wireshark Lua dissector

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a Wireshark dissector in Lua. Is there a way to get the network interface the current frame was received on/transmitted from within the dissector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a frame field called `frame.interface_id`, available since Wireshark 1.8.0 according to the Wireshark [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html) page, which should give you the ID of the interface.  The ID seems to match the enumeration given in the results of `dumpcap -D` (or `tshark -D`) if you subtract 1 from the enumeration.  In other words, both dumpcap and tshark count interfaces starting with 1 in the respective `-D` outputs, while Wireshark seems to start counting from 0.  This inconsistency seems like a bug to me and I would suggest filing a [Wireshark bug report](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) against this inconsistent behavior.

**EDIT** (since it seems impossible to format this in a coherent way using comments):

To access the field, you would use a field extractor, see: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Field.html

For example:

```
local fe_interface_id = Field.new("frame.interface_id")

function foo.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    local f_interface_id = fe_interface_id()
    pinfo.cols.info:append(", Interface ID=" .. tostring(f_interface_id))
end
```

Comment: FYI: I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13496

Comment: As the bug comments indicate, the `frame.interface_id` field represents the value of the interface to be written to the pcapng file, which doesn't correspond to `{tshark,dumpcap} -D` output at all.  The first interface specified will be assigned index 0, the next index 1, and so on.  Whether this behavior for `frame.interface_id` changes remains to be seen, but I doubt it; therefore you just need to be aware of what its value represents.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the bug report. Can you show me how I can access the frame field within a dissector? (i.e. within the `Proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)` function). More specifically, I'd like to use the value to modify what's shown in `pinfo.cols.info`.